# Model null on submit in asp mvc.net form if using ajax to request data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, forms, post

I would like to know how to do it right or circumvent a problem I have.

I have an ASP MVC.NET 5 page with a model. On the [HttpGet]Index() I prepare the model and pass it to the view. The view contains @Html.EditorFor and @Html.DropdownFor input fields for the model properties. At the end is a singular submit button to send/POST the form to the controller and its [httppost]Index(MyModel model) controller method, which accepts the model as an input parameter. All dandy, all fine.

Now I want to dynamically change contents of dropdowns when the user selects the topmost dropdown, selects an entry then other dropdowns shall change as well.

The way I found to do it was to use javascript and .onchange(function(){.$.ajax(postdata)}) to generate a POST-request, this request is sent to a controller method, the controller generates a json-reply with new string lists, and then these strings are put into the other dropdowns. This works fine. I can click on the dropdowns, select values, and other dropdowns dynamically change content, and so forth. All dandy, all fine.

The view contains a few other fields, for the name of the user, or a phone number field, and so forth.

When the user fills in the data, selects dropdowns, and finally submits the form the controller method receives and empty/null model! Why is the controller receiving a null model?

I think I found the answer. Only the first POST inside a FORM wins with all the information available, following POSTS dont have all of them anymore.

The browser receives the page, and inside the page is the form tag. Inside this form-body an element is clicked/changed - the dropdown - and using javascript generates a POST-request to the server. Once this POST is done - the small reply is used to update other dropdowns inside the form-body - all further "data" in the browsers "memory" seem to be lost. When the user clicks the last submit button and generates a POST to the server, the browser sends .. nothing. Therefore the model being passed to the controller is null.

So: How can I update dynamically controls using javascript/ajax/jquery with bits of information from the controller while being inside an ASP MVC.NET 5 form, without using a POST request which seems to break the form processing?

Or: How can I send my model data on the final submit button to the controller, using javascript/ajax/jquery, and receive a new View as reply?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I named a property of the model 'Model' and that broke the processing. Once I renamed it the page final submit started to work. Sometimes things are as simple as that, yet with unseen consequences - at first.